# Looking for middle grades/young adult horror fantasy book

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, horror

I am writing this for a friend, but we should be able to respond quickly to details.

---

This book was popular around the mid 2000s. It was a horror/fantasy novel that featured a cartoonish, maybe graphic-novel-style cover, in vibrant colors with an old haunted-looking house on the front. The book itself was not a graphic novel. The story had something to do with a friend or neighbor of two siblings possibly being a werewolf (although I hesitate to add this detail because I worry it's misremembered). It is not one of the Goosebumps series, but the cover style reminds me of this series.

Thinking more on the book, I believe the title maybe had a number in it (potentially ten) and it potentially had the word "secret" or "confessions". I don't think the title had werewolf in it, and that may have been a subplot.

I would be so grateful if this sparks a memory from someone! Any details or tips that would improve my search would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Is it one of the *Scream Street* books, perhaps?

[image: Front cover of Scream Street: Fang of the Vampire]

All of the series books have a similar cover style. The book involves a boy (forgot his name) who is a werewolf. He lives in the normal world until, one day, he transforms into his wolf form and tries to bite a chihuahua, who turned out to be a shapeshifting agent of some organization whose purpose is capturing those like him (Werewolves and other monsters) and sending them to live in another world. I believe that he may or may not have had siblings. The book series involves him and his friends going on a quest to procure some magical artifacts in order to open a portal back to the normal world so that he may reunite with his family and go back home. I haven't read the whole series, but I believe one of the books has an ending where he does succeed in opening a portal to the normal world, but decides to stay because he has already come to call his new world his home and because going back would mean abandoning the friends that he made in the monster world.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, this isn't it - the plot summary doesn't spark my memory. However, thinking more on the book, I believe the title maybe had a number in it (potentially ten) and it potentially had the word "secret" or "confessions". I don't think the title had werewolf in it. I'll add these details to the question.